# Eclipse blurs text when scroll bar is used

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, eclipse

In the Eclipse text editor, when I click and drag the horizontal scrollbar, the screen does not "refresh" or "update" properly, resulting in a blurry image.  This behavior has not been observed in any other program.

**Note:** I cannot take screenshots because when I press the print screen button, it refreshes the screen and fixes the problem.  The photos below were taken with my phone:

**Screenshot 1**
I just opened this file.  The screen looks fine.

[image]

**Screenshot 2**
After dragging the horizontal scrollbar to the right.  Notice how the text in the editor is significantly blurred.  No, that is not the camera.

[image]

**Screenshot 3**
After pressing `Ctrl+A`.  The text has come back into focus.  This is my workaround for resolving this issue.

[image]

**Hardware/software information**

- Computer device: netbook
- Eclipse: Luna 4.4.2 (downloaded from Eclipse's homepage).
- Distro: CrunchBang (old version, before it became BunsenLabs.  However, I keep the software updated)
- CPU: Intel Atom
- Video card: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
- Memory: 2GB
- `lshw` output: https://gist.github.com/mangstadt/6897b07653077aa66abe1cf88c573e9d

Comment: That's probably an Eclipse bug, but it could be a video driver bug. What exact version of Eclipse do you have (version number, and how you obtained the binary)? What exact model of graphics card and what version of X and what driver (e.g. nv, nvidia, nouveau, …), on what distribution? Is Eclipse the only application where you've seen such visual glitches?

Comment: @Gilles Please see my edited question.  Yes, this is the only application I've experienced this problem on.

Comment: Integrated video card: but what exact model? Driver bugs are often specific to a specific model. You can find out with `lshw` (or any other way to list available hardware).

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the tip.  I'm not sure how to reliably interpret the output of the `lshw` command, so I included its entire output (see the link at the bottom of the question).  I also revised my question in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, @Gilles.  I look forward to seeing my question be removed from held status.

Comment: @Gilles I re-edited my question some time ago, but it was never removed from "closed" status.  How can it be re-opened?  I'm still experiencing this problem and would like to keep the question open in the hope that it will receive an answer.  Thank you.